# Why can't I access my superclass methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using LBYouTubePlayer to play videos in my app.

In the framework LBYouTubePlayer, it's subclassed as mpmovieplayercontroller, declared as

```
@interface LBYouTubePlayerViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController
```

In my own view controller, I do

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LBYouTubePlayerViewController* videoPlayerController;
```

and video plays successfully with

```
    self.videoPlayerController = [[LBYouTubePlayerViewController alloc] initWithYouTubeID:stringID quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualitySmall];
    self.videoPlayerController.delegate = self;        
    [self.viewForPlayer addSubview:self.videoPlayerController.view];
```

but when I try

```
[self.videoPlayerController setControlStyle:  MPMovieControlStyleDefault ];
```

the method isn't recognized? even when I do self.videoPlayerController, autocomplete pops up but does not show any of the superclass' methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no in `setControlStyle` method in [MPMoviePlayerViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: yup you're right. In case someone runs into a similar problem, I fixed it by changing the superclass to MPMoviePlayerController (instead of MPMoviePlayerViewController).